# Proof of differential calculus / vector formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I want to prove the following foumula, but I have no idea.

Let $$f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$$be a smooth function.
and $$g = \nabla f , t\in \mathbb{R}, x \in \mathbb{R}^3 .$$

Then, $$ \frac{d}{dt} f(tx) = x \cdot g(tx) $$

Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about the chain rule for differentiable mappings between multidimensional spaces? If $h:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ and $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^p$ then their derivatives $Dh$ and $Df$ can be considered as matrices of sizes $n\times m$ and $p\times n,$ respectively. The composed mapping $f\circ h:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^p$ is also differentiable, and its derivative is the matrix product of the individual derivatives:

$$D(f\circ h)=(Df\circ h)\cdot Dh.$$

Now apply this with $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3:t\mapsto tx.$

Comment: I  think it should be $D(f\circ h)=(Df \circ h) \cdot Dh$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!